# Extend Laravel Schema Builder create function

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've searched in the docs and fiddled with the Laravel code but found nothing about it. I'm using Laravel 5.1.

I want to know if I can extend the Schema::create function or do something in terms of reverse migration. I want to recover the fields and types set during migration and output them to a json file for each migration file (there are many).
This file will be used in [angular formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/).
This way I can generate everything during the migration command.

I believe repeating the code for each migration is not the best approach. Any ideas?

```
class CreatePlanTypesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('plan_types', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->dateTime('created_at');
            $table->dateTime('updated_at');

            // ---- dont want to repeat for each migration file -----
            $json = [];

            $columns = $table->getColumns();

            foreach($columns as $column)
            {
                $json[] = [
                    'key' => $column['name'],
                    'type' => $column['type'],
                    'templateOptions' => [
                        'label' => '',
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ]
                ];
            }
            file_put_contents('tablefile.json', json_encode($json));
            // -------------------
        });
    }
    ...
```